# C++ How to resize a dynamic array without losing data?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I need to resize a dynamic array without losing data.

Like this:

```
double * pVecDin;//POINTER

int num_values = 2;
pVecDin = new double[num_values];

pVecDin[0]=5;
pVecDin[1]=6;


int new_num_values=4;
pVecDin = new double[new_num_values];


//Next I lost value of pVecDin[0] and pVecDin[1]
pVecDin[2]=8;
pVecDin[3]=9;
```

Do I need make an `Auxiliar Dynamic Array` to copy the old values?
Like:

```
int new_num_values=4;
double * pVecDin_aux; //POINTER

pVecDin_aux = new double[new_num_values];
pVecDin_aux = pVecDin;

for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
  pVecDin_aux[i] = pVecDin[i];
}
```

Comment: just use `std::vector` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a new, empty array with the new desired size.
2. Copy everything in the old array to the new array.
3. Delete the old array.
4. Assign the pointer of the old array to the address of the new array.

---

Or use a `vector`.

Comment: You mean: Use a vector. OR do the other things

Answer (score 0):

As nhgrif has mentioned, you need to make copy of the array.

There is another way if you can use `malloc` for memory allocation, then you can use `realloc` for resizing the array.

There are better ways as suggested by other like to use `std::vector` or `list`.